# Cannot fill temporary table from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, nullreferenceexception

During a gridview => database update function, I use a column-by-column conversion to string in order to pass data back to my database as a whole command string. I'm aware that this sounds convoluted, so here is an example:

**Classes in use:**
`InvoiceHandler.cs`
`Default.aspx.cs`

Since this is a rather large snippet, here is a pastebin:

**Default.aspx.cs:** http://pastebin.com/Y3fJZ36Z

**InvoiceHandler.cs:** http://pastebin.com/ZsdAnDxr

At the first point of conversion (`invoiceTableEdited.Columns["Column1"].ColumnName = "@K_INV";`) I get a NullReferenceException error, assumedly because the method call in Default.aspx.cs

`handler.invoiceTableEdited = ViewState["invoiceTable"] as DataTable;
            handler.invoiceTableEdited.Rows[row.RowIndex]["K_INVOICE"] = sK_INVOICE;`

appears to be having trouble.

What must I do to resolve this?

Comment: "Appears to be having trouble" is not very helpful. Try telling us the error or the current results vs the expected results.

Comment: Looks like you get the exception because you're trying to assign a name to a column in the columns collection of invoiceTableEdited when no columns have been created.

Comment: @sr28 Are you sure? In Default.aspx.cs, in the method `OnUpdate` I create those columns out of the row in the `GridView`?

Comment: My mistake. However, in Default.aspx.cs you are creating ["column1"] etc and in InvoiceHandler.cs you try and assign the name to ["Column1"]. Try altering that to be ["column1"].

Comment: @sr28 I'd ignore the column names. I had to change them all in a rush to anonymise them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be honest, it's not very clear how you're trying to create the column collection for the table 'InvoiceTableEdited'. What it looks like you're doing in OnUpdate is you are assigning a string variable to a row in the table with a given index and a column that doesn't currently exist. Your basically saying put this string into a cell with a row number of 'x' and a column name of "column1". At this point "column1" doesn't exist.

I'd create the columns you need first in InvoiceHandler.cs like this (assumes they're string):

```
invoiceTableEdited.Columns.Add("MyColumn1", typeof(string));
invoiceTableEdited.Columns.Add("MyColumn2", typeof(string));
```

Obviously if you have loads of columns and you don't care about their names then just create a loop and add them that way. This will give them the naming convention "ColumnN", where 'N' is the number. You can then assign a name to them by referencing there name ("Column1" for example) or using their index.

Comment: I looked at what this was actually doing, and realised I don't need the extra table. In fact, I'm already extracting the data from the gridview as strings at the beginning of `onupdate()`, so I'm using those. 

I do appreciate your help, you were correct that the requisite column did not exist in memory.